# Is my plan for an undermount sink repair reasonable?

Tags: repair, sink

The top right corner of our undermount sink collapsed a few inches the other day. Underneath the sink it's got 1x3 boards attached to the back and side wall and holding the sink up in certain spots, which I understand to be common. No clips. It looks like one of the 1x3 boards is a bit loose.

I temporarily braced the sink in the meantime. My plan is to lower the sink in that corner again, scrap away the adhesive, use E6000 adhesive (I've seen it recommended for this specific application) and brace it back up. I'll also be using epoxy to set some clips to the underside of our granite countertop, letting them sit a day and then using the clips for the sink (something else I also read about). Then I'll be setting the 1x3 brace back into place. I may even temporarily put a 2x4 under the sink in the event that the 1x3 doesn't fully sit right. Then I'll silicone the inside of the sink again.

Does this all sound appropriate? I figure I'll have 3 ways of support - clips, adhesive, wood bracing. I'm not dropping the whole sink and redoing it all, just the corner that actually fell down a few inches. Anything else to consider?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Got pics so we can see what you see?